# Locations dissappearing from events

Tags: civievent, civivolunteer, location

We are having an issue with Civi location settings. We begin by making a copy of the same type of event and updating it with the new event information (correct time and date, description.) Then we save and publish the new event. For some reason, when we do this with our volunteer events, the location will often disappear from other events using the same location or it will change to another location that we have used for a different event.

Comment: Hi Addison welcome to civicrm stackexchange. Can you update your question with what version of civicrm you are using. There is a recent bug which involves event location - perhaps confirm that this isn't related https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/653